# Как выравнять все ячейки по центру таблицы кроме первого ряда таблицы на css

Tags: html, css

Как выравнять все ячейки по центру таблицы (кроме первого ряда таблицы) на css?

```css
table tr:not(td):first-child {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
table tr:not(:first-child) td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

P.S. Если под фразой "*кроме первого ряда*" имелась в виду первая колонка, то

```
table tr td:not(:first-child) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
table.row tr:not(:first-child) td {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ff0;
}
table.col tr td:not(:first-child) {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<table class="row">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="col">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

добавить

```
table tr:first-child td{
  text-align:left;
}
```